# Invalidate field from controller

Tags: forms, cakephp, invalidation

I have an action/view that is going to be used for reporting purposes, no saving of data involved.

I want some form elements to be valid/invalid and if invalid, some errors to be shown.

What is the most CakePHPish way for showing errors in form fields that are not based on a model?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're not getting or saving your data from a database table, you still need a model for validation rules, that's the proper MVC way. You can set

```
var $useTable = false;
```

In your model if you're not planning on saving/reading anything. You can then use your model to just set your validation rules and messages.

Comment: A model is available, however the form fields are not used for saving. Eg the model has a date_action field, and I have two form fields: date_action_form, date_action_to

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your data without saving, within the controller like so:

```
$this->ModelName->validates()
```

For more information, please refer here: [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller)